# При сборке путь шрифтов генерируется не правильно. Как это исправить?

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, scss

У меня тут такая проблема с webpack, что пути в font-face для шрифтов после сборки генерируются не правильно.

Вот так выглядит файл конфигураций:

```
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: "babel-loader",
        exclude: "/node_modules/",
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: "file-loader",
        options: {
          name: "[name].[ext]",
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/i,
        loader: "file-loader",
        options: {
          name: `${Paths.assets}fonts/[name].[ext]`,
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(sass|css|scss)$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: "postcss-loader",
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
              postcssOptions: {
                plugins: ["autoprefixer", "css-mqpacker", "cssnano"],
              },
            },
          },
          {
            loader: "sass-loader",
            options: { sourceMap: true },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  }
```

Вот папка dist после сборки:

[image: Директоря dist]

Файл fonts.scss:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Monsterrat_700";
  src: url("../fonts/Montserrat/Bold-700/Montserrat-Bold.ttf")
      format("truetype"),
    url("../fonts/Montserrat/Bold-700/Montserrat-Bold.woff") format("woff"),
    url("../fonts/Montserrat/Bold-700/Montserrat-Bold.woff2") format("woff2");
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: norml;
    font-display: swap;
}
```

И вот этот путь получаю в конце:

```
@font-face {
  font-display: swap;
  font-family: Monsterrat_700;
  font-style: norml;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: url(assets/fonts/Montserrat-Bold.ttf) format("truetype"),
      url(assets/fonts/Montserrat-Bold.woff) format("woff"),
      url(assets/fonts/Montserrat-Bold.woff2) format("woff2")
}
```

Буду благодарен каждым ответам, комментариям.

Точно такой же вопрос был задан 4 года назад, но без ответов. Надеюсь кто то решил это проблему и даст на этот вопрос ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Так как я не получил ответ от других программистов, решился ответить на собственный вопрос. Если кто то столкнулся с такой проблемой, то это будет полезной информацией.

Долго копался в интернете но в русскоязычных сайтах ничего не нашёл и только на англоязычных сайтах нашёл зацепку и по этой зацепке начал экспериментировать с кодом что стал причиной решения этого вопроса.

Нужно было добавить несколько строчек кода в файл конфигураций.

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: "babel-loader",
        exclude: "/node_modules/",
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: "file-loader",
        options: {
          name: "[name].[ext]",
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/i,
        loader: "file-loader",
        options: {
          name: `[path][name]_[contenthash:8].[ext]`,
          context: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/"),
          outputPath: 'assets/',
          publicPath: '../',
          useRelativePaths: true,
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.(sass|css|scss)$/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: "postcss-loader",
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
              postcssOptions: {
                plugins: ["autoprefixer", "css-mqpacker", "cssnano"],
              },
            },
          },
          {
            loader: "sass-loader",
            options: { sourceMap: true },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
```

Также можно решить вопрос с путём для изображений.